# How can i use $ in x(i,j) - GAMS

Tags: syntax, gams-math

i tried this & doesn't work and given errors something like that.

> EQUATIONS
>   ST3(i$(ord(i) LE (5) and ord(i) GE (1)),k$(ord(k) LE (19) and ord(k) GE (1)));
>
> ****       $10,185                            $195,96
>
> ST3(i$(ord(i) LE (5) and ord(i) GE (1)),k$(ord(k) LE (19) and ord(k) GE (1))) ..
>
> ****       $148,8                            $36                             $409
>
> IN(i,k) + sum(j, X(j,k+1)*p(i,j)) + W(i,k+1) -  W(i,k) - sum(j, X(j,k)*p(i+1,j)) - IN(i+1,k) =E=0;

8  ')' expected

10  ',' expected

36  '=' or '..' or ':=' or '$=' operator expected
     rest of statement ignored

96  Blank needed between identifier and text
       (-or- illegal character in identifier)
       (-or- check for missing ';' on previous line)

148  Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
        indices as declared

185  Set identifier or '*' expected

195  Symbol redefined with a different type

409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
       looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again

how can i fix these code part?

Answer (score 0):

GAMS will not accept $ expressions in equation declarations (or any declarations). Also, in equation definitions, the $ expression must be specified after the domain.

This should work:

```
EQUATIONS ST3(i,k);
ST3(i,k)$(ord(i) LE 5 and ord(i) GE 1 and ord(k) LE 19 and ord(k) GE 1) ..
IN(i,k) + sum(j, X(j,k+1)*p(i,j)) + W(i,k+1) - W(i,k) - sum(j, X(j,k)*p(i+1,j)) - IN(i+1,k) =E=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

VRp,k = VRZEROp + RPp, k × δ 
p, k=1
VRp,k variable
VRZEROp parameter
RPp, k   parameter

How this equation is identified on Gams for k=1